# Crash at XMLScanner::CommonInit of Xerces

Tags: xerces

We use `XercesDOMParser` in our `DLL`. Our DLLs run on `IIS 7`, application pool and we are experiencing crash on IIS 7 worker process startup. The crash occurs randomly.

Stack trace from the crash dump  is as follows (from WinDebug):

```
0000000`017ad970 00000000`120810bb xerces_c_3_1!xercesc_3_1::XMLScanner::commonInit+0x1e
00000000`017ad9c0 00000000`1205b3c4 xerces_c_3_1!xercesc_3_1::XMLScanner::XMLScanner+0x413
00000000`017ada40 00000000`12086969 xerces_c_3_1!xercesc_3_1::IGXMLScanner::IGXMLScanner+0x20
00000000`017adab0 00000000`1209b0e4 xerces_c_3_1!xercesc_3_1::XMLScannerResolver::getDefaultScanner+0x4d
00000000`017adb00 00000000`1209ada8 xerces_c_3_1!xercesc_3_1::AbstractDOMParser::initialize+0x74
00000000`017adb50 00000000`120aa392 xerces_c_3_1!xercesc_3_1::AbstractDOMParser::AbstractDOMParser+0x100
00000000`017adbc0 00000000`01635cf0 xerces_c_3_1!xercesc_3_1::XercesDOMParser::XercesDOMParser+0xe
00000000`017adbf0 00000000`0163686f EmbeddedConfigurationClient!GACreateConfigurationClient+0x4bbf
//...
```

Why do we face this crash on process startup? Any clues on fixing the issue? We are instantiating XercesDOMParser from our constructor after calling `XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize()`

I have the following info. Also from the crash dump:

```
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_xerces-c_3_1.dll!xercesc_3_1::XMLScanner::commonInit

AULTING_IP: 
xerces_c_3_1!xercesc_3_1::XMLScanner::commonInit+1e
00000000`12082d6a 488b0b          mov     rcx,qword ptr [rbx]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000012082d6a (xerces_c_3_1!xercesc_3_1::XMLScanner::commonInit+0x000000000000001e)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000000
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000000

PROCESS_NAME:  w3wp.exe
```

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:

```
Use '!findthebuild' command to search for the target build information.
If the build information is available, run '!findthebuild -s ; .reload' to set symbol path and load symbols.

FAULTING_MODULE: 0000000077bb0000 ntdll    
DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4bd18e21    
ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.    
EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.    
EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000   
EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000000    
READ_ADDRESS:  0000000000000000
```

I have the `Xerces C++` code, but could not figure out which line of code is causing the issue.
Any help to resolve the issue is much appreciated.

Regards,
George

Answer (score 0):

Just incase it  helps someone.. The root cause was that multiple threads were accessing Xerces code
at the same time. We have updated the code (sometime back) and the issue is resolved.

Regards,
George

Comment: @Rizier123 This is an answer.